# Resize UIView with constraints

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an `UIView` (350x350) with a class where I create a circle in the middle of the view (`x: frame.width/2`, `y: frame.height/2`). Now I want that `UIView` to be smaller on smaller devices. I use storyboard constraints for that. The view gets smaller but the circle still uses the 350px to calculate the center.

[image]

[image]

**This is how I create the circle:**

```swift
fileprivate func loadBgProgressBar() {

        let startAngle = CGFloat(-Double.pi / 2)
        let endAngle = CGFloat(3 * Double.pi / 2)
        let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: frame.width/2 , y: frame.height/2)

        let gradientMaskLayer = gradientMaskBg()
        bgProgressLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter:centerPoint, radius: frame.width/2 - 10.0, startAngle:startAngle, endAngle:endAngle, clockwise: true).cgPath
        bgProgressLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        bgProgressLayer.fillColor = nil
        bgProgressLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        bgProgressLayer.lineWidth = 4.0
        bgProgressLayer.strokeStart = 0.0
        bgProgressLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0

        gradientMaskLayer.mask = bgProgressLayer
        layer.addSublayer(gradientMaskLayer)
    }


    fileprivate func gradientMaskBg() -> CAGradientLayer {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        let colorTop: AnyObject = CustomColor.flipside.cgColor
        let colorBottom: AnyObject = CustomColor.flipside.cgColor
        let arrayOfColors: [AnyObject] = [colorTop, colorBottom]
        gradientLayer.colors = arrayOfColors

        return gradientLayer
    }
```

Comment: How do you create the circle?

Comment: Using a CAShapeLayer

Comment: can you please show the code ?

Comment: I have added the code

Answer (score -1):

Use viewDidLayoutSubviews to resize your Layer,

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
     super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
     layer.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.width/2, y: view.bounds.height/2, view.bounds.width - 10, view.bounds.height-10)
    }
```

Comment: Conceptually this is right (using `viewDidLayoutSubviews`), though obviously the `frame` is not right and you want to update the path for the mask and gradient, too.